# How to copy the elements in class A to class B in python?

Tags: python, class, copy, domain-driven-design

Currently there are class `DomainA` and class `ServiceA`, I want to copy the value in `DomainA` to `ServiceA` or copy the value in `ServiceA` to `DomainA`. Currently my implementation is as follows. This implementation is inflexible and not reusable. Are there any libs or modules that have been implemented?

```py
class ServiceA(object):
        def __init__(self, api_name=None, author=None, region=None):
        self.api_name = api_name
        self.author = author
        self.region = region

class DomainA(models.Model):
    api_name = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

# my impl for convertor.
class Convertor:
    def __init__(self):
        super(Convertor, self).__init__()
    
# Are there any libs or modules that have been implemented for convertor?
    def BoToDo(self, bo: ServiceA) -> DomainA:
        do = DomainA()
        if bo.api_name is not None:
            do.api_name = bo.api_name
        if bo.author is not None:
            do.author = bo.author
        if bo.region is not None:
            do.region = bo.region

        return do

    def DoToBo(self, do: DomainA) -> ServiceA:
        pass
```

I don't expect deep or shallow copies of different instances of the same class, because here are different classes. Can anyone help? Thank you very much.

Comment: why are you not subclassing DomainA against ServiceA?

Comment: Because they don't have this relationship. In fact, `DomainA` here is a model corresponding to a db-table, and `ServiceA` is a service. You can refer to the convert from Bo (Business Object) to Do (domain object) in domain-driven-design.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `__dict__` to get all attributes of `ServiceA` object, check for conditions (in this case, not null) and set the attributes to `DomainA` object.

```
class Convertor:
    def __init__(self):
        super(Convertor, self).__init__()

    def BoToDo(self, bo: ServiceA) -> DomainA:
        do = DomainA()
        # loop through ServiceA object attributes
        for attr_name, val in bo.__dict__.items():
            # if attribute is not None, set the attribute to DomainA
            if val is not None:
                setattr(do, attr_name, val)

        return do
```

However, by looking at `DomainA` class, it may have data validation during initialization. using `set_attr` may bypass validation. In that case, you can get all attributes of `ServiceA` objects, filter out null values, and pass to `DomainA` during object initialization.

```
class Convertor:
    def __init__(self):
        super(Convertor, self).__init__()

    def BoToDo(self, bo: ServiceA) -> DomainA:
        # filter out null values
        attrs = {attr_name: val for attr_name, val in bo.__dict__.items() if val is not None}
        
        # create DomainA object with filtered attributes
        do = DomainA(**attrs)

        return do
```

Please note that in order to use this method, `ServiceA` and `DomainA` attributes must be the same.